# How to prevent input other characters than I need it?

Tags: java

I am using this piece of code to get characters from users. If someone put "k" my program is closed.
If someone put anything else for example "a" or "b" etc. my program works again from the beginning.

How to code in this way that If someone put anything else for example 1, 2 or 3 or z, it prints "it is not allowed character, please correct it"

I want to have a second character to start the program from the beginning for example "f".

```
                while (!end) { //do something
                Scanner st = new Scanner(System.in);
                String str = st.nextLine();
                if (str.equals("k")) {
                    end = true;}
```

Comment: You could use an `else` statement which will print "Invalid character" whenever it is not "k", "a" etc.

Answer (score 0):

You just need an else block in your code. Check this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WhileLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean end = false;
        while (!end) { //do something
            Scanner st = new Scanner(System.in);
            String str = st.nextLine();
            if (str.equals("k")) {
                end = true;
                System.out.println("Will exit the program now since you have entered k");
            } else {
                System.out.println("it is not allowed character, please correct it");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not a sulution because if I input for example "s" my program display "it is not allowed character, please correct it" but it restart. It starts again.

Comment: Do you want the program to terminate when you input "s"? If so, please add `System.exit(0)` in the else part. By doing so, It will stop the program.

Comment: It should stop and user has to input the correct character, only "k" or "a" nothing else

Comment: I have added exit condition in the code. If it is not allowed character, program will stop.

Comment: I know about it.

Comment: Alright, @TJstock. By the way, I never said that you do not know. I just meant that we can add if we want the program to stop.

Comment: But it is not a solution for my question anyway

Comment: Gentleman, you need to ask a clear question to get the appropriate answer. Asking an ambiguous question will get an answer of this kind only. I am trying to help you and you are showing this attitude.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you should get characters from the user, so you do not need to define a string variable, you need to define a character variable and read characters from the user , No need to use `st.nextLine()` Instead, use with `st.next().charAt(0)`.

In addition, you need added the statement `else` .

```
boolean end = false;
    while (!end) { //do something
        Scanner st = new Scanner(System.in);
        char str = st.next().charAt(0); 
        if (str=='k') {
            end = true;}
        else {
        System.out.println(" is not a valid character. Please try again.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would go about doing it:

```
outer:
while (true) {
    //do stuff before
    System.out.println("before");

    while (true) {
        Scanner st = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = st.nextLine();

        if (str.equals("k")) {
            break outer;
        } else if (str.equals("f")) {
            continue outer;
        }

        System.out.println('"' + str + "\" is not a valid character. Please try again.");
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work in correct way. If I put "k" my program is closed. This is nice. If I input for example "a" or "b" or 1, 3 etc it displays it is not allowed character, please correct it but the program starts from the beginning. It should stop and user has to input the correct character, only "k" or "f" nothing else

Comment: I just updated the code so that the program exits the loop when an invalid character is entered.  Is that closer to what you were looking for?

Comment: No it is not. It should be stopped and user has to input the correct character, only "k" or "f"

Comment: Then I am misunderstanding your problem.  What do you want the program to do when the user enters "a"?  What do you mean by "it should be stopped"?  If you want to get input from the user again, you need to go back to the beginning of the loop.

Comment: I've updated the code to include a nested loop, so "a" will only go to the beginning of the inner loop, and "f" will go to the beginning of the outer loop.  Am I any closer now?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use an `else`-statement. Such as:

```
while (!end) { //do something
    Scanner st = new Scanner(System.in);
    char str = st.next().charAt(0); 
    if (str == 'k')) {
        end = true;
    } else if (str == 'a')) {
        // handle program work from the beginning
    } else {
        System.out.println("it is not allowed character, please correct it");
    }
}
```

What this does is to check if `str` is equals to `"k"` or `"a"`, and if not it will print the text message you provided.

> In programming languages, an else statement is an alternative statement that is executed if the result of a previous test condition evaluates to false.

Comment: It doesn't work in correct way. If I put "k" my program is closed. This is nice. If I input for example "a" or "b" or 1, 3 etc it displays it is not allowed character, please correct it but the program starts from the beginning. It should stop and user has to input the correct character, only "k" or "a" nothing else.

Comment: @TJstock if you only want to compare one character I would suggest you use my edited solution and read about what `nextLine()` does: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanner-nextline-method-in-java-with-examples/. I believe this should work for you though. Keep in mind, I do not do anything in the comparison with `a`. And also, now we are comparing a `char` and not a `string` anymore.